# (React Native IOS) images doesn't load external links

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, info.plist

My react native app running in IOS doesn't load images with external links unless added to info.plist.

My question is, How do I configure my info.plist so it can accept all external links instead of adding multiple links in my info.plist.

Comment: how are you adding the URL to images

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.